# How can I center this table on my site?

Tags: html, css

I have two tables with ads on my site.

The top one seems to be centered, but the bottom one isn't centering.

I tried adding a bunch of code to center the table, but it doesn't seem to be working.

The current code looks like this:

```
<div align="center">
<table align="center" style="text-align:center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 20px 0px;">
<tr style="height:100px">
<td><span id="ad1"></span></td>
<td><span id="ad5"></span></td>
<td><span id="ad4"></span></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

What can I do to center it correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: width of the table contents exceeding the parent width; fix that first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't appear centered because the table + images is wider than the div containing it.
I added a few inline styles, seen below, that makes it look correct, but you really should either resize the width of the container or use images that fit the container you have.

Essentially, I added a max-width:100% to the table and to the images within the table.

```
<div align="center" style=" text-align: center;">
    <table align="center" style="text-align:center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; border-collapse:separate; border-spacing: 20px 0px; max-width:100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr style="height:100px">
                <td>
                    <span id="ad1">
                        <a href="http://ltm.me/ad1" title="Amp Cellular" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://jewishmusicstream.com/ads/amp.jpg" width="300" height="100" style="max-width: 100%;">
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ad5">
                        <a href="http://ltm.me/ad5" title="Get Peyd" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://jewishmusicstream.com/ads/getpeyd.gif" width="300" height="100" style="max-width: 100%;">
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span id="ad4">
                        <a href="http://ltm.me/ad4" title="The Kosher Chocolatier" target="_blank">
                            <img src="http://jewishmusicstream.com/ads/thekosherchocolatier.png" width="300" height="100" style="max-width: 100%;">
                        </a>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Any way of seeing which div is restricting it, so I can change that div width?

Comment: Your main container div (<div class="container clearfix">) is 960px wide. The content-area div then sets a 50px padding on each side, so your content is narrowed down to 860px wide. Your table, with images, is 986px wide. You have three images at ~300px wide each, so even with no gaps between them the images are more than your 860px content area. Add to that that you've got a 20px border spacing between the imags and you're at 980px, which is wider than the main container of 960px.

Comment: Changed that to 1100px, and it seems to work...